# Setting frames in Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I am trying to port little app from `html/javascript` page to `Sharepoint` page. I am new to SP world and would greatly appreciate your help.

I am trying two have two frames side by side **50%/50%** (Page View Web Parts?) and one control frame under them (**height 80%/20%**).

So my question is how should i do it? I tried using table but i have to set row height in pixels so that doesn't work too well for me. Should I use Zones? Or something else?

Also how can i pass web address to Page View Web Part and show it (like setting frame `.src` in `html`)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're familiar with HTML/Javascript you should use [sharepoint designer](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/related-technologies/pages/sharepoint-designer.aspx) to create and modify a custom page, and that will give you full control over the page area.

You can create a page, then detach from page layout - this will copy the markup from the page layout that you selected and allow you to edit the page directly.  From there, I would just do something simple like having 2 div's for your (50/50 area) and then 1 control div (for the 20% area), and use CSS to style your frames.